# How did the different ranks of sith compare to their jedi counterparts?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, sith

In Legends there are a number of different [Sith ranks](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith/Legends#Sith_Empire) before Darth Bane's Rule of Two and I was curious as to how the different Sith ranks would compare to their counterparts. **For example, how would a Jedi Knight compare to a Sith Warrior (and similar)?**

I get the impression that the Sith were often weaker than their Jedi counterparts as suggested by this cinematic movie from SWTOR where the Sith warriors(?) are easily being attacked by non-force-sensitive republic troopers:

So how would Sith compare to their Jedi equivalent in terms of their skill and strength (e.g- would a Sith accolyte be as skilled and be able to defeat a Jedi padawan?)

Comment: This seems like it's going to be opinion based. Are you asking how each rank differed in **strength** and who would win in a fight, or which rank was the status **equivalent** of the other?

Comment: Oddly enough, 3000 years later Jedi get jumped by a ton of troopers too, so would that make them weaker? A lot of the cinematics for SWtOR was to show off the classes and how they can be heroic or powerful as well. In the game's predecessors (KotoR 1) we see Jedi get taken down by 'normal' people as well.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd I am asking about how their **Skill** and **strength** would compare

Comment: @Boolean Your edit is asking the same POB question. It would help if you thought of a totally different way to get the same information. One that could be clearly answered using *facts*, and not what someone *thinks*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I grabbed the list of common Sith ranks from [this wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith/Legends#Ranks) article. As may be obvious, the higher ranks and their equivalents are stronger than lower ranks.

- **Dark Lord of the Sith**
  These were the recognized leaders of the Sith. Comparable to the **Jedi Council**, though it was a rank for the sith as opposed to simply a position like the Jedi
- **Sith Lord**
  These were also leaders of the Sith who's level of power depened mostly on which era we are talking about. They are comparable to **Jedi Masters**.
- **Sith Marauder and Sith Warrior**
  Similer to **Jedi Knights**, these two positions are basically the same thing with different specialties. Marauderers tended to be more combat focused and Warriors more Force focused.
- **Sith Acolyte and Sith Adept**
  These are the equivilent of **Jedi Padawans**. They are force-sensitive apprentices who had only just started down the dark path under the tutelage of a more experienced Sith.
- **Sith Assassin and Sith Minion**
  These two ranks are the lowest, mostly because non-force-sensitive being could be among them. They tended to worship the Sith as gods and were used as soldiers, mercenaries, and conscripts in the Sith Armies. There is no real Jedi equivilent.

As a note, there is no Sith equivilent of a **Jedi Initiate (Youngling)**.